# VB.NET Filtering with a Linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've been tasked with adding a filtering mechanism to a result set.  I understand the basic concepts of filtering using the Where clause in Linq, however there HAS to be a better way to do this, right?

Scenario: 
I have 5 filterable columns on my result set.  I have to take into account all variations of these 5 filters at any given time.  This means that I have to manually type out an If/ElseIf statement with 120 different variations!

Here's the general way of how things are going and I just simply need to ask: Is there a better, quicker way to do this?!

The Filters

```
ByVal SearchMxMID As Integer,
ByVal SearchProfile As Integer,
ByVal SearchCZ As String,
ByVal SearchTerm As Integer,
ByVal SearchFwMth As Integer
```

The course of the If statements

```
If SearchMxMID = 0 
And SearchProfile = 0 
And SearchCZ =    "All" 
And SearchTerm = 0 
And SearchFwMth = 0 Then

Dim queryMM = (From a In DBPricingContext.tbl_Matrix_Margins
               Where a.CompanyID = CInt(sCompanyID)
               Order By a.Profile
               Select a)
Return New StoreResult(queryMM)

ElseIf SearchMxMID > 0 
And SearchProfile = 0 
And SearchCZ =    "All" 
And SearchTerm = 0 
And SearchFwMth = 0 Then
Dim queryMM = (From a In DBPricingContext.tbl_Matrix_Margins
               Where a.CompanyID = CInt(sCompanyID) And a.MarGroupID = SearchMxMID
               Order By a.Profile
               Select a)
Return New StoreResult(queryMM)
```

ETC
ETC
ETC

120 total times for each combination of these 5 filters (whether they are blank or have values).  Is there a quicker way i can do this, something maybe in 1 single Linq query?

```
If SearchMxMID > 0 Then a.MarGroupID = SearchMxMID Else DO NOT APPLY WHERE CLAUSE
```

???

Comment: **Scenario: I have 5 filterable columns on my result set. I have to take into account all variations of these 5 filters at any given time. This means that I have to manually type out an If/ElseIf statement with 120 different variations!** No, you don't. Only use what's relevant - yes, you'd have five IF statements for your where block, but you just need to  to plug values in. I do this all the time in SQL, so it should also be possible in Linq. I'd use IN in SQL, there are similar features in Linq.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the `Where` clauses and construct your query dynamically like this:

```
Dim query = DBPricingContext.tbl_Matrix_Margins.AsQueryable()

If compID > 0 Then
    query = query.Where(Function(a) a.CompanyID = compID)
End If
If SearchMxMID > 0 Then
    query = query.Where(Function(a) a.MarGroupID = SearchMxMID)
End If
...

query = query.OrderBy(Function(a) a.Profile)
```

This scales well with many columns, as there will be only one If-statement per column.

Note that I am using the extension method syntax and lambda expressions instead of the specialized LINQ query syntax. A call to `Select` is not necessary, if you are just selecting the parameter `a` itself.

If you are using LINQ-to-Objects instead of LINQ-to-some_database, then replace the `AsQueryable()` by `AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Linq queries are chainable. You could simply have a single if per your case and if it is true then add another where. ie (in C# but should be easy to follow for any .Net coder - or you can use Telerik's code converter and revise the code a bit):

```
string country = "Germany";
string city = "Berlin";
int? productId = 3;

var data = db.Customers;

var result = data.AsQueryable();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
{
  result = result.Where(r => r.Country == country);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
{
  result = result.Where(r => r.City == city);
}
if (productId.HasValue)
{
  result = result
  .Where(r =>
     r.Orders.Any(o =>
       o.OrderDetails
        .Any(od => od.ProductID == productId.Value)));

}
```

Another way is to is to simply use a NULL or ... approach. ie:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim country As String = ""  '"Brazil"
    Dim city As String = "" '"Sao Paulo"
  Dim orderDate As System.Nullable(Of DateTime) = Nothing   'new DateTime(1996,8,28);

    Dim data = Orders.Where(Function(c) _
     String.IsNullOrEmpty(country) OrElse c.ShipCountry.StartsWith(country)) _
     .Where(Function(c) String.IsNullOrEmpty(city) OrElse c.ShipCity.StartsWith(city)) _
     .Where(Function(c) orderDate Is Nothing OrElse c.OrderDate = orderDate) _
     .Select(Function(c) New Order() With { _
         .OrderId = c.OrderID, _
         .CustomerId = c.CustomerID, _
         .OrderDate = c.OrderDate, _
         .ShipCountry = c.ShipCountry, _
         .ShipCity = c.ShipCity _
    })

    Dim f As New Form() With { .Text = "Query Results" }
    Dim dgv As New DataGridView() With { .Dock = DockStyle.Fill }
    f.Controls.Add(dgv)

    dgv.DataSource = data.ToList()
    f.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Public Class Order
    Public Property OrderId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_OrderId
        End Get
        Set
            m_OrderId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_OrderId As Integer
    Public Property OrderDate() As System.Nullable(Of DateTime)
        Get
            Return m_OrderDate
        End Get
        Set
            m_OrderDate = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_OrderDate As System.Nullable(Of DateTime)
    Public Property CustomerId() As String
        Get
            Return m_CustomerId
        End Get
        Set
            m_CustomerId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_CustomerId As String
    Public Property ShipCountry() As String
        Get
            Return m_ShipCountry
        End Get
        Set
            m_ShipCountry = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ShipCountry As String
    Public Property ShipCity() As String
        Get
            Return m_ShipCity
        End Get
        Set
            m_ShipCity = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ShipCity As String
End Class
```

Note: Code is Linq To SQL code. With EF this wouldn't be supported and you need to use the former approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compose the queries in series using the LINQ syntax.

```
Dim TempQuery = (From a In DbPricingContext.tbl_Matrix_Margins
                 Where a.CompanyID = CInt(sCompanyID)
                 Select a)

If SearchMxMID > 0 Then
    TempQuery = (From a In TempQuery
                 Where a.MarGroupID = SearchMxMID
                 Select a)
End If

'... Add your other conditions in here...

Return New StoreResult(From a In TempQuery Order By a.Profile Select a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use logic like `SearchValue = DefaultValue OrElse SearchValue = PropertyValue`

```
Dim result = DBPricingContext.tbl_Matrix_Margins.
                 Where(Function(a) a.CompanyID = CInt(sCompanyID)).
                 Where(Function(a) SearchMxMID = 0 OrElse a.MarGroupID = SearchMxMID)
```

And add other search conditions in the same way.
It will return all rows if `SearchMxMID = 0` and return only matched rows if `SearchMxMID <> 0`

For accuracy result I will be used `Nullable` type

```
Where(Function(a) SearchMxMID.HasValue = False OrElse a.MarGroupID = SearchMxMID.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a specification pattern. Something like this:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim someList As New List(Of SomeClass)

        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now

        someList.Add(New SomeClass() With {.Id = 1, .Title = "001", .EntryDate = now})
        someList.Add(New SomeClass() With {.Id = 2, .Title = "002", .EntryDate = now.AddSeconds(10)})
        someList.Add(New SomeClass() With {.Id = 3, .Title = "003", .EntryDate = now.AddSeconds(20)})

        Dim idParam As Integer = 1
        Dim titleParam As String = "" '"001"
        Dim dateParam As DateTime = now



        ' first approach, one selector
        Dim selector As Func(Of SomeClass, Boolean) = Function(item)
                                                          With item
                                                              Return ((idParam <= 0) OrElse (.Id = idParam)) AndAlso
                                                                  ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(titleParam)) OrElse (.Title = titleParam)) AndAlso
                                                                  ((dateParam.CompareTo(DateTime.MinValue) = 0) OrElse (.EntryDate = dateParam))
                                                          End With
                                                      End Function



        Dim list = From o In someList Where selector(o) Select o

        For Each o In list
            Console.WriteLine(o)
        Next



        ' second approach, one selector per parameter
        Dim selectorId As Func(Of SomeClass, Boolean) = Function(item)
                                                            Return ((idParam <= 0) OrElse (item.Id = idParam))
                                                        End Function


        Dim selectorTitle As Func(Of SomeClass, Boolean) = Function(item)
                                                               Return ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(titleParam)) OrElse (item.Title = titleParam))
                                                           End Function


        Dim selectorEntryDate As Func(Of SomeClass, Boolean) = Function(item)
                                                                   Return ((dateParam.CompareTo(DateTime.MinValue) = 0) OrElse (item.EntryDate = dateParam))
                                                               End Function

        Dim list2 = From o In someList
                    Where
                    selectorId(o) AndAlso
                    selectorTitle(o) AndAlso
                    selectorEntryDate(o)
                    Select o

        For Each o In list2
            Console.WriteLine(o)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Class SomeClass
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property Title As String
        Public Property EntryDate As DateTime

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("Id:{0}  Title:{1}  EntryDate:{2}", Id, Title, EntryDate)
        End Function
    End Class
```

Hope this example helps you a bit.